# Carrierwave: Use spaces instead of underscore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

We have an uploader for PDF's. When a file name has spaces in it, they are automatically being converted to use underscores:

`some file test` -> `some_file_test`

I'd like to keep the spaces. Can someone tell me how?

I tried:

```
  def filename
    original_filename
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override [sanitize regexp](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/9a37fc9e7ce2937c66d5419ce1943ed114385beb/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb#L21-L25) by adding whitespace:

```
CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.sanitize_regexp = /[^[:word:]\.\-\+\ ]/
```

As you see this regexp used in `sanitize` [method](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/9a37fc9e7ce2937c66d5419ce1943ed114385beb/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb#L319) that replace forbidden symbols to underscore.

From [CarrierWave documentation](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#filenames-and-unicode-chars):

> **Filenames and unicode chars**
>
> Another security issue you should care for is the file names (see [Ruby On Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#file-uploads)). By default, CarrierWave provides only English letters, arabic numerals and some symbols as white-listed characters in the file name. If you want to support local scripts (Cyrillic letters, letters with diacritics and so on), you have to override `sanitize_regexp` method. It should return regular expression which would match all *non*-allowed symbols.
>
> ```
> CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.sanitize_regexp = /[^[:word:]\.\-\+]/
> ```
>
> Also make sure that allowing non-latin characters won't cause a compatibility issue with a third-party plugins or client-side software.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`original_filename.gsub("_", " ")`

UPDATE (possible workaround):

- Replace underscores with a character or a string (e.g. "xyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyz") you are not expecting in filenames before passing them to carrierwave i.e.

```
  filename.gsub("_", "your_special_character/s")
```

- Replace underscores with spaces and special character with underscores later:

```
  original_filename.gsub("_", " ")
  original_filename.gsub("your_special_character/s", "_")
```

Comment: I'd like to preserve file names that actually do have an underscore...just not convert spaces to underscore

Comment: That is a little tricky but you can put an if condition around the above line which should only allow this to execute if your original_filename is not equal to name of any file present in your folder? That's all I can think of rn. sleepy :P Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help, but using a class override is a much better solution.